# How to manage and motivate external workers in project?

Tags: motivation, external-project-members

In one of projects I work we have some people working only partially. They come to work only when there is a need for their work in project and sometimes they work at home.

The problem is with commitment - when they are not part of the team they aren't motivated. When they work at home it's hard to get output from them.

What you recommend? How to make them participate more in the project?

How to deal with remote workers not doing their work on time?

Answer (score 3):

This one is tricky because the team members who work from home are more in control of the contact.

Keeping them up to date is a good way for them to feel connected. An e-newsletter is a good tool for that. Making sure you reach out to them periodically when their work is coming up will also help.

One thing to keep in mind, if they are producing what you need on time and in budget, they may be as committed as you need them.

Answer (score 3):

Remote workers can be managed effectively using tools such as Skype Instant Messaging and Skype Video Calls.  It's important to meet frequently and keep those channels open and take an active role in providing updates.

Similarly, you need to create a culture where the workers do the same and contact you to give you proactive updates.  If the work done is something of a specialty, like programming, then having the workers working at a remote location can give them more freedom and autonomy to make effective decisions on their own.

Just like with in office workers, it's important that deadlines are clear and that there are clear communication channels for situations where a deadline might be missed, such as if unexpected problems result.

Remote workers should be treated with the same level of professionalism as in-office workers.  By keeping them in the loop, encouraging proactive communication both ways, and by utilizing the latest remote workforce technologies, remote teams can be just as effective as in-office teams.

For part-time workers, the same guidelines can help them stay motivated.  With part-time workers, it's easy to forget to keep them informed, especially if they're not around for certain meetings or communications.

Here is an article with some tips for how to [Keep Part-Time Employees Motivated](http://www.suite101.com/content/keeping-parttime-employees-motivated-a152401) and feeling like they're part of the group and have great skills to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

> When they work at home it's hard to get output from them.

What do you do when you don't get output from an on-site worker? What project management instruments are you using in this case? I'm sure that the same instruments should work perfectly with off-site people. Provided these instruments do not include [carrot and stick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_and_stick).

Answer (score 0):

Find new people who are hungry for the work.

Comment: but those who possess enough skills maybe hard to find. It's sometimes not preferable to train a part-time employee.

Comment: If the issue is motivation, it will either be cost effective to live with the lack of commitment or make more financial sense to get someone with greater commitment even if they cost more.